# chown and chmod automaticly on boot

Tags: linux, samba

I've created a samba share, but in order to give myself permission to access it completely I needed to use the following commands:

sudo chown –R root:users /mnt/My_Network_Drive

and

sudo chmod –R ug+rwx,o+rx-w /mnt/My_Network_Drive

Now this worked great, however when I restarted my Raspberry Pi that I'm using for this samba share, I needed to enter these commands again in order for it to work.

Is there any way I can have those commands automatically work on reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should correct this by passing the corresponding options `uid` and `gid` to `mount` instead of using `chmod` afterwards. If you don't use `mount` directly you can also set those options in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

try putting them in /etc/rc.local